# What's the best code editor for Mac with right-to-left support?

Tags: text-editor, json, macos

I'm trying to work with JSON files that have bidirectional text. I recently have been using the BBEdit free trial, and while it's a great app, it's nearly impossible to edit text that isn't left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

The only editor I could find with right-to-left support is TextEdit which comes standard on a mac.  It's not a code editor in that it doesn't support syntax highlighting but it will edit text files. To get to the right-to-left mode see the following figure.

[image]